# Define observation_space For custom gym environment

Tags: openai-gym

I am working on a problem that I want to implement as a reinforcement learning problem and integrate with OpenAI's Gym.

The environment has 96 states. In each state we observe 3 elements

[home_Loard, SOC_, Price_].

how could I make my observation space to be compatible with Gym.

Comment: What kind of values can these states take?

Comment: they are all float32 value

Comment: So is it a 96x3 matrix/vector?

Comment: so we have 96 State. and every state is define with 3 element